# java pid keep increasing

Tags: java, debian, cpu

We have Tomcat application running in a Debian 6.07 Server.
Lately CPU used were increasing gradually.
Using Top command I noticed that Java PID keep increasing everyday.
I need to restart the tomcat to make it back to normal.

After restart the tomcat, Java Cpu Used will be back to around 2 %.
From that moment it will increase everyday, and I will need to restart the tomcat every time it reach around 40 %.

Is there any way to fix this issues ?

Thank you

Comment: PID as in *process id*? It is just an identifier - it does not matter if it increases. Your real problem is the CPU usage, it seems. Please clarify why you have to restart tomcat.

Comment: I restart tomcat because Java PID keep increasing. After Restart tomcat, only 2 Java PID was running. then It will increase like 5 then 10 then 40, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some memory leak or some thread which consumes memory or processing iteratively without freeing unused resources.

Also, you may use tools like Java Profiler (or any other java auditing and profiling tools) to analyze what resources are being used and by whom (classes, threads... etc.)

checkout the following links for Java profiling tools:

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/06/java-performance-tuning-tools/

http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source

(if you can share more info I'll edit my answer properly)

Comment: Thank you in advance, I used cron to run  (ps -eLf |grep java >> process$NOW.txt) every 30 minutes.                                                    
I noticed that pid keep increasing like below.
--root     26336     1  4090  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4091  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4092  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4093  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4094  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4095  0  212 May14
--root     26336     1  4096  0  212 May14